# Search in FileListbox by edit component

Tags: delphi

I want to know how can I search strings in a `Filelistbox` by edit component. The content of the `Filelistbox` is about 100 txt files.I have a half solution, but I want to add the results to the `Filelistbox`, not the `Listbox`. Any idea? And must I use the Listbox1 or can I make it without somehow? Thanks for help and sorry for my eng :)!

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If Edit1.Text = EmptyStr then
    ListBox1.Items := FileListBox1.Items
  else
  begin
    ListBox1.Clear;
    For I := 0 To Pred(FileListBox1.Items.Count) do
    begin
      If AnsiPos(Edit1.Text, FileListBox1.Items[I]) <> 0 then
      begin
        ListBox1.Items.Add(FileListBox1.Items[I]);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `TFileListBox` is a Windows 3.1 compatible control (very outdated) that lists files in a folder. To add items to it, you add files to the folder; there's no way to just add items to `TFileListBox`. (You shouldn't be using `TFileListBox` anyway, IMO; it makes your applications look very outdated and unprofessional. I think they should have dropped it and `TDirectoryListBox` and `TDriveComboBox` from the VCL a decade ago; they're only there now for backward-compatibility with Delphi 1.)

Comment: You need to hold your data in a separate list, which should be a `TStringList`. Then use the edit box as a filter and each time there is a change to the edit box, update the file list box. And as Ken says, stop using file list box. You can use a plain list box to displayed the filtered list. Or a `TListView`. Use `IOUtils` to populate your list of files.

Comment: Its a simple program, i need only txt files. Ok but how can i change that code for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably make use of the built-in `Mask` property. I'd guess something like the below would filter the files as you'd expect:

```
procedure TForm1.Edit1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FileListBox1.Mask := '*' + Edit1.Text + '*';
end;
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.FileCtrl.TFileListBox.Mask) about how the mask works.

Comment: I want to list the results in the Filelistbox not the Listbox.

Comment: @Steve - That's what this answer does, there's no reference to a listbox in this answer.

Comment: +1. Nice job of reading between the lines to figure out what the real question was - I didn't get to the same conclusion at all. (I thought the poster was asking about putting the matching files into a separate `TFileListBox`.)